# Give "hitbox" to overlay tikzpicture

Tags: tikz-pgf, floats, geometry

I want to have a nice banner at the top of the page when I start a new chapter.
I have made one that I'm happy with using a tikzpicture with overlay.
However I can't get its "hitbox" (bounding box?) correct.
If I simply start writing after the tikzpicture, the text will be put on top since the banner's height is greater than the top margin.

In order to get the text on the correct place I added `\vspace*{...}` after the banner where `...` was substituted by the correct heights. This worked well for text. The code and output can be seen below:

```
\documentclass{report}

\newcommand{\margin}{2.5cm}
\newcommand{\bannerheight}{5cm}
\usepackage[a4paper, margin = \margin]{geometry}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\definecolor{SnowBlue}{RGB}{230, 240, 250}
\providecommand{\ChapterColorA}{SnowBlue}

\begin{document}
    \stepcounter{chapter}
    ~
    \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture, every node/.style = {scale = 2, inner sep = 0cm, outer sep = 0cm}]
        \coordinate (nw) at (current page.north west);
        \coordinate (se) at ($(current page.north east)-(0,\bannerheight)$);
        
        \fill[\ChapterColorA] (nw) rectangle (se);
        
        \node[anchor = north west] (title) at ($(nw)+(\margin, -\margin)$) {\huge\textbf{Cool Chapter}};
        
        \node[anchor = south west] () at (title.north west) {\large\textbf{Chapter \thechapter}};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    ~
    \newline
    \vspace*{\dimexpr(\bannerheight+1ex-\headsep-\headheight-\margin)}
    \newline\newline
    ~
    \lipsum[1]

    \begin{table}
        \centering
        \begin{tabular}{l}
            I \\ am \\ a \\ floating \\ table \\ that \\ 
            likes \\ to \\ hide \\ under \\ the \\ banner
        \end{tabular}
        \caption{A little table. :)}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

However, if there is a float that wants to sit at the top of the page, it is put under the banner, and then the `\vspace*{...}` is applied between the table and the text. See output below:

[image]

I then had the idea of using `\newgeometry{top = \dimexpr(\bannerheight+1ex)}` which worked well for both the text and the table, but then I would also have to use `\restoregeometry` which would imply a manual page break. That, of course, is not desirable.

How could I make all other elements of the document respect the presence of the banner without manual tweaking at every new chapter?

> Edit: I made changes according to Tom's kind suggestions. Since `\@makechapterhead` seemed to only affect the graphical part of the chapter (and som line break penalty) I felt like I could simply redefine the whole thing without much risk. In any case there are no longer any problems with text or floats that want to overlap with the banner. The code and the output can be found below. :)

```
\documentclass[oneside]{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcommand{\margin}{2.5cm}
\newcommand{\bannerheight}{5cm}
\usepackage[a4paper, margin = \margin]{geometry}

\newcommand{\titlecolor}{black}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\newcommand{\mybanner}%
{%
    \fill[blue!30] (nw) rectangle (se);
}

\makeatletter%
\def\@makechapterhead#1%
{%
    \tikz%
    [%
        remember picture,%
        overlay,%
        title/.style={inner sep = 0cm, outer sep = 0cm, color = \titlecolor, scale = 2}%
    ]%
    {%
        \coordinate (nw) at (current page.north west);
        \coordinate[yshift=-\bannerheight] (se) at (current page.north east);
        \coordinate (c) at ($(nw)!0.5!(se)$);
        
        \clip (nw) rectangle (se);%
        \tikzset{shift={(c)}}
        \mybanner%
        
        \node[anchor=north west, title] (title) at ($(nw)+(\margin, -\margin)$) {\bfseries\Huge#1};%
        \node[anchor=south west, title] () at (title.north west) {\bfseries\Large\@chapapp\space \thechapter};%
    }%
    \vspace{\dimexpr(-\margin+\bannerheight+1em)}%
    \par%
}%
\makeatother%

\begin{document}
    \chapter{Cool Chapter}
    
    \lipsum[1-3]
    
    \renewcommand{\titlecolor}{white}
    \renewcommand{\mybanner}
    {
        \node[yshift=2cm] {\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]{test-image}};
        \fill[violet, opacity=0.3] (nw) rectangle (se);
    }  
    
    \chapter{Cooler Chapter}
    
    \lipsum[4]
\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: `overlay` tells Ti*k*z  to consider the size of the picture zero... Maybe you can avoid it? There are several packages that will let you style chapters and section, look for example at `titlesec`.

Comment: @Rmano I tried out `titlesec`, but I didn't understand how to use it from the manual. However it seemed that it does approximately the same thing as suggested in Tom's answer, that is redefine `\chapter`. Would it be preferable in some way to do it using `titlesec` instead of redefining it directly?

Comment: yes, it does more or less the same. The `titlesec` package, though, stramline that for chapters, section, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could patch the `\@makechapterhead`. And patch the `\@makeschapterhead` as well, if you want the star version `\chapter*{}` have a banner too (e.g. `\tableofcontents`). By default, the floats won't appear in the chapter heading page.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\newcommand{\margin}{2.5cm}
\newcommand{\bannerheight}{5cm}
\usepackage[a4paper, margin = \margin]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\definecolor{SnowBlue}{RGB}{230, 240, 250}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@makechapterhead}{\vspace*{50\p@}}{\relax}{}{}
\patchcmd{\@makechapterhead}{\@chapapp}{%
\tikz[remember picture,overlay,shift={(current page.north west)}]{
\fill[SnowBlue] (0,0) rectangle ([yshift=-\bannerheight]current page.north east);
}\@chapapp%
}{}{}
\patchcmd{\@makeschapterhead}{\vspace*{50\p@}}{\relax}{}{}
\patchcmd{\@makeschapterhead}{\bfseries}{%
\bfseries\tikz[remember picture,overlay,shift={(current page.north west)}]{
\fill[SnowBlue] (0,0) rectangle ([yshift=-\bannerheight]current page.north east);
}%
}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Cool Chapter}
\lipsum[1-14]
\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{l}
I \\ am \\ a \\ floating \\ table \\ that \\ 
likes \\ to \\ hide \\ under \\ the \\ banner
\end{tabular}
\caption{A little table. :)}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

> Edit: You could patch the command by putting a macro there (e.g. `\mybanner`), and each time before you start a new chapter, you just redefine that macro with different contents:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\newcommand{\margin}{2.5cm}
\newcommand{\bannerheight}{5cm}
\usepackage[a4paper, margin = \margin]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\definecolor{SnowBlue}{RGB}{230, 240, 250}
\newcommand{\mybanner}{%
\tikz[remember picture,overlay,shift={(current page.north west)}]{
\fill[SnowBlue] (0,0) rectangle ([yshift=-\bannerheight]current page.north east);
}%
}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@makechapterhead}{\vspace*{50\p@}}{\relax}{}{}
\patchcmd{\@makechapterhead}{\@chapapp}{%
\mybanner\@chapapp%
}{}{}
\patchcmd{\@makeschapterhead}{\vspace*{50\p@}}{\relax}{}{}
\patchcmd{\@makeschapterhead}{\bfseries}{%
\bfseries\mybanner%
}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Cool Chapter}
\lipsum[1-14]
\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{l}
I \\ am \\ a \\ floating \\ table \\ that \\ 
likes \\ to \\ hide \\ under \\ the \\ banner
\end{tabular}
\caption{A little table. :)}
\end{table}
\renewcommand{\mybanner}{%
\tikz[remember picture,overlay,shift={(current page.north west)}]{
\fill[yellow,opacity=0.4] (0,0) rectangle ([yshift=-\bannerheight]current page.north east);
}%
}
\chapter{Cool Chapter 2}
\renewcommand{\mybanner}{%
\tikz[remember picture,overlay,shift={(current page.north west)}]{
\node [opacity=0.2] at ([shift={(0.5*\paperwidth,-0.5*\bannerheight)}]0,0) {\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\bannerheight]{example-image-plain}};
}%
}
\chapter{Cool Chapter 3}
\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thank you for your help! Unfortunately this is not completely working for me since I want different content in my `tikzpicture` for every chapter. Maybe I made my MWE to minimal. :P Do you think that I could send the content of the banner as a `pic` in an argument? Also, do you know where one can find the documentation for `\@makeschapterhead`? I can't completely understand what you have done without seeing it I think.

Comment: @Racersnigeln The `\@makeschapterhead` command was defined in `cls` file. IF consider report class, for example, I am using windows with MiKTeX, the path I am looking for `report.cls` is in `C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\report.cls`. And the `\chapter` define is start from line 329

Comment: @Racersnigeln You definitely can do that, depends on what is your objective. You wanna different pictures as banner for different chapters?

Comment: Thanks for the pointer towards the definition! My plan is to have one colour scheme per chapter to be used in table title rows and such, so at the chapter start I would like to set the tone. I would like to have a photo or a `tikzpicture` in the banner and tone it with the colour scheme by filling with a low opacity.

Comment: @Racersnigeln I edit the answer, to include some potential tweaks you could do.

Comment: I edited my response with a new suggestion. Since `\@makechapterhead` only seemed to alter the graphical aspects of the chapter I redefined it alltogether instead. The only thing I found risky was removing the `\interlinepenalty\@M`, but that can always be added. What do you think? Do you have any other suggestions? :)

Comment: @Racersnigeln I think your definition is fine in particular for your use case.  In the original definition, there is also a if statement `\ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne` to determine if the chapter will be numbered or not depends on the counter value of `secnumdepth`. However in most of case, chapter should be numbered.

Comment: @Racersnigeln And you only redefine the `\@makechapterhead`, how about the star version of the `\chapter` command. For example, `\tableofcontens`, `listofigures` and `listoftables` will all use `\chapter*{}` to type the heading. I assume you will use `\tableofcontens` in your doucment. This will make you whole document layout are not same. You probably need to redefine `\@makeschapterhead` as well.

Comment: @Racersnigeln You two nodes seems to close to each other,  you could use `above` option in the second node to add some space.